# Почему не работает col-sm-offset-1?

Tags: html, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Приветствую. Есть хедер, в нем лого и две картинки в ряду с надписью. Пытаюсь с помощью бутстраповской сетки сделать адаптивные блоки, чтобы они красиво складывались между собой. колдую с отступами `col-sm-offset-1`, но почему-то не применяется и на малом изображении блоки как-то непонятно группируются между собой, вместо того, что располагаться один под одним по центру.
Пример в [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13863/)

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 header-logo">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
          </a>
        </div>
        <h4>текст</h4>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-sm-6 -->
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span class="table">
  <div class="pull-left"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
  <span class="cell">еще текст</span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-sm-6 -->
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
  </div>
  <!-- end container -->
</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Блок не может рассчитать свою высоту из-за потомков с примененным обтеканием.

Вы пытаетесь исправить это с помощью хелпера `.clear`, вот только в Bootstrap он называется `.clearfix`

Comment: Что значит не применяется? На разрешениях меньше 768px перестает работать указатель `sm`. Дальше нужен `xs`, а его вы сами его не указываете. Если вы о том, что не получается сделать отступы с помощью `col-xs-offset-*`, то в Bootstrap 3.0.0 для `xs` разрешений этих классов не существует. В этой версии есть только `col-sm-offset-*`, `col-md-offset-*` и `col-lg-offset-*`. Чтобы воспользоваться классом `col-xs-offset-*`, вам необходим Bootstrap с версией не ниже 3.1

Comment: да, спасибо - не та версия сеточной системы была, даже `col-sm-offset-*` не воспринимала